# Export to .xls works on dev environment but not on production / Failed - Network Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to find issues with my code, and it is working perfectly in my dev environment, but not on production. This is not an issue with the browser (Firefox, IE, and Chrome all three fail), and neither is it an issue with the size of the file, as other questions here indicate. I thought that it could be a Token problem, since I didn't provide one at first, but after implementing it I find the problem is still present.

The file shows `Failed - Network Error` when prompted to download.

Here are some code bits, starting from client-side

```
generateExcel( ){
        this.detector.markForCheck( );
        this.api.post( 'invoice/excel_liquidation', { liquidation: this.list } ).subscribe( ( response: any ) => {
            if( response.success ) { 
                this.toast.success( 'Excel correctly generated!' );
                let url = response.file.url // + '?token=' + this.auth.jwt;
                this.generateDownloadUrl( url, response.file.name );
                this.detector.markForCheck( );
            }
            this.detector.markForCheck( );
        }, ( error: any ) => {
            this.detector.markForCheck( );
        });
    }

generateDownloadUrl( url: string, name: string ) {
        let a    = document.createElement( 'a' );
        a.href   = url;
        a.download = name;
        document.body.appendChild( a );
        a.click( );

        a.remove( );

    }
```

And finally the server-side (except parsing, and other unnecessary data):

```
exportExcel: ( headers, content, file_name ) => {       
        /* SOME ERROR HANDLING */
        if( !file_name ) file_name = 'export-' + app.date.now( 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss' );
        let file = '';      
        headers.map( header => {
            if( typeof header === 'string' && header.toString( ).trim( ) !== '' ) header = header.toString( ).trim( ).replace( /_/g, ' ' ).toUpperCase( );
            file += header + '\t';
        });
        file += '\n';
        content.map( row => {
            headers.map( header => {
                file += row[ header ] + '\t';
            });
            file += '\n';
        });
        let save_file = app.paths.storage + 'temp/' + file_name + '.xls'; 
        return fs.writeFileAsync( save_file, file, 'utf-8' ).then( ( ) => {
            return Promise.resolve( { path: save_file } );
        });
    },
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is this defined? app.paths.storage

Comment: It is defined like this:

`paths: { storage:  path.join( __dirname, '../../../', 'app/storage/' ) },`

Comment: And have you checked that on the server, that path points to the right spot, and that spot is writable by the application? Maybe log it out somewhere so you can see the path?

Comment: It is being correctly generated in server side, since I can access and see the file on FileZilla. Or at least that is my understanding.

Comment: That's super helpful to know  =)

Comment: Permissions is the other gotcha I've run in to - does the application serving the file have permissions to it.

Comment: Oh, and another thing to check: response.file.url is correct, and is a location accessible by the web. Since it's just a normal link, it has to be somewhere the server will allow direct access to.

Comment: Regarding permissions: I tried to generate it running Chrome as root, and ran into the same problem. However, I'm not quite sure what you're referring when you say 'the application serving the file'. I tried to log the URL and access it manually, but I found a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Well, I'm used to IIS, and the way it's configured, the application runs as an account, and that account has to have read permissions to the directory/file being served. Additionally, files served over http live in wwwroot or a mapped location. If you can't access it from chrome as a link, that's probably your issue - it's not being saved somewhere that's exposed as an http spot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I don't quite understand what you're talking about, but you have gave me nudge in the right direction I think. Thank you.

Comment: I am not a node person, but this looks promising if that's what you're using as a web server? (see setting up a public directory) https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-node-and-express-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after modifying the previous method like this:

```
 generateDownloadUrl( url: string, name: string ) {
            let a    = document.createElement( 'a' );
            a.href   = url;
            /*a.download = name;*/
            a.target = '_blank';
            document.body.appendChild( a );
            a.click( );
            a.remove( );

        }
```

In short, trying to open the .xls file in a new tab instead of directly downloading it served as a workaround for the issue.